# Pandas set all values after first NaN to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For each row I would like to set all values to NaN after the appearance of the first NaN. E.g.:

```
    a    b    c    
1   2    3    4    
2   nan  2    nan  
3   3    nan  23
```

Should become this:

```
    a    b    c    
1   2    3    4    
2   nan  nan  nan  
3   3    nan  nan
```

So far I only know how to do this with an apply with a for loop over each column per row - it's very slow!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check with `cumprod`

```
df=df.where(df.notna().cumprod(axis=1).eq(1))
     a    b    c
1  2.0  3.0  4.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Adding to this; avoid looping in Pandas if possible! This solution is much better than an approach that uses `itertuples` or `iterrows`. Also, thanks for teaching me something new!